# ID and class in css and their precedence

Tags: html, css

```
<div id="idblue" class="blue"></div>
```

My application is used in 2 different browsers.

I have defined the id="idblue" in only 1 broswer .css file and want that browser to take only id and not the class="blue" at all as id is placed first and it takes precedence than class.

What is happening is id and class are getting implemented. But i need only id to be implemented in this browser. Appreciate your inputs.

I am retaining the class="blue" so that the other browser works fine with just class="blue" and also id="idblue" is not defined in the .css file of this browser.

Comment: Please explain what do you mean by two browsers? and it seems like you are using two separate css files? can't you remove the class="blue" on one? Can you provide with more details please.

Comment: What is the purpose of this request? If you're trying to overcome some sort of horrid IE versioning issue or something you might benefit from modernizr to target by feature support.